# Uniform field through a disc

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, induction

Let us say that we have a magnetic field of the form $B_0 \sin(\omega t) \hat e_z$ in all space. Now let us say we put a conducting disc within this field. I want to find the electric field within this disc but I have come up with a problem.

The electric field lines are going to be closed and I assume circular (as they are in a solenoid which could be used to produces such a field).

Consider the following diagram:
[image]

It is my assumption that the field will be as shown in A rather then in B. I.e. the field lines concentric with the disc. I cannot, however, think of a justification for this - to me both do seem equally valid. So, if I am correct in saying that the field will be as shown in A, why? and if not please can you explain what the field lines will look like.